# Loading xml and dll from subfolder

Tags: c#, xml, dll, nuget

I have an c# project using a nuget package and I don't know how to change to loading file of the .dll and .xml files. When I build the project now I get the .exe, .dll and .xml in the same folder. I would like to move them to a subfolder (basically so that the .xml and .dll are in a different folder than the .exe).

This is the first time I am using a nuget package.

Comment: That is not related to packages, you will normally get all binary files in the output folder. And that is a good thing.

Comment: And is there any way to change that?

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not going to help you, unless you provide some compelling reasons to do this.

Comment: Well the reason is impracticality. Relatively a large amount of people are going to use this and I am convinced that some of them will delete the binary files because the will think that they are not needed.

Comment: Never mind, solved.

Comment: You still shouldn't do it.

Comment: I actually didn't. I decided to make a shortcut and put everything into a subfolder. Unfortunately I have a different issue now. I am opening the .exe using a batch file but it won't open it if the path contains a dot. Do you know how to solve this? Or should I post another question?